# Insert a key using Ruamel

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am using the Ruamel Python library to programmatically edit human-edited YAML files.  The source files have keys that are sorted alphabetically.

I'm not sure if this is a basic Python question, or a Ruamel question, but all methods I have tried to sort Ruamel's OrderedDict structure are failing for me.

I am quite confused, for instance, why the following code, based on [this recipe](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes), isn't working:

```python
import ruamel.yaml
import collections

def read_file(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as _f:
        return ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(
            _f.read(),
            preserve_quotes=True
        )

def write_file(f, data):
    with open(f, 'w') as _f:
        _f.write(ruamel.yaml.dump(
            data,
            Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper,
            explicit_start=True,
            width=1024
        ))

data = read_file('in.yaml')
data = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
write_file('out.yaml', data)
```

But given this input file:

```
---
bananas: 1
apples: 2
```

The following output file is produced:

```
--- !!omap
- apples: 2
- bananas: 1
```

I.e. it's turned my file into a YAML ordered map.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Also, can I simply insert into the data structure somehow?

Comment: Also puzzling is that when I view the transformation in the Python debugger, it appears to have worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you round_trip a mapping in `ruamel.yaml`¹ , a mapping doesn't get represented as a `collections.OrderedDict()`, it gets represented as a `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()`. The latter can be a subclass of `collections.OrderedDict()` depending on which version of Python you are working with (e.g. in Python 2 it uses the much faster C implementation from`ruamel.ordereddict`)

The representer doesn't automatically interpret "normal" ordered dictionaries (whether from `collections` or `ruamel.ordereddict`) as special in round_trip_dump mode. But if you drop the `collections`:

```
import ruamel.yaml

def read_file(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as _f:
        return ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(
            _f.read(),
            preserve_quotes=True
        )

def write_file(f, data):
    with open(f, 'w') as _f:
        ruamel.yaml.dump(
            data,
            stream=_f,
            Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper,
            explicit_start=True,
            width=1024
        )

data = read_file('in.yaml')
data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
write_file('out.yaml', data)
```

your `out.yaml` will be:

```
---
apples: 2
bananas: 1
```

Please note that I also removed an inefficiency in your `write_file` routine. If you don't specify a stream, all data will be streamed to a `StringIO` instance first (in memory) and then returned (which you wrote to a stream with `_f.write()`, it is much more efficient to directly write to the stream.

As for your final question: yes you can insert using:

```
data.insert(1, 'apricot', 3)
```

---

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of both [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) as well as [ruamel.ordereddict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.ordereddict).</sub>

Comment: If you want to preserve comments from the original YAML file, you can copy the `_yaml_comment` attribute from your **original** `data` to the newly created `CommentedMap()`

Comment: Thank you again, that worked perfectly, and I can also preserve the comments.